# how can i increase the height of a row in @media print function

Tags: css

i wants to get a printout.for that i have written a media print function.its working fine.but i want to increase height of a row which that print epf no and name.how can i do that.

Here is the current preview[image]

here is my code

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print{
        .total-sheet-td {height: 40px; vertical-align:  middle;}
        .printbutton {display: none}
        .pay-sheet {border: none;}
        .pay-sheet td {height: 35px !important;}
        .pay-sheet .txt-al {text-align: center}
        .pay-sheet .txt-al-r {text-align: right; padding-right: 2px;}
        .pay-sheet .emt-row {height: 60px;border-right: none; border-left: none;}
        .pay-sheet .emt-cell {border-right: none; border-left: none; }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: did you tried min-height for ".total-sheet-td ".. instead of height?

Comment: have you tried applying the height change to the parent `tr` instead of the `td` itself?

Comment: Add `padding` to `.pay-sheet td`

Answer (score 0):

in your `@media print` just change the height of the whole `tr`

```
 @media print{
    tr {height:40px;}
 }
```

or you could add padding to the desired td

```
 @media print{
    .total-sheet-td {padding:20px 0}
 }
```

plus i made a simple example .

i used a JQ to simulate what happens when you print, respectively , increasing the 'tr' height. so you can see that by increasing the `tr` height, after clicking on the print button, will work.

```js
$(".printbutton").click(function(){
  $("tr").css({"height":"100px"})
})
```

```css
tr { background:cyan}
tr {height: 50px; vertical-align:  middle;}
table,td { border-collapse:collapse;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>

</table>
<button class="printbutton">
Click to Print
</button>
```